# How to eliminate "else-if" statements

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

My function get QueryString from some Web page as a `string`.
I need to parce it, to check, what strategy i must use.

Now my code looks ugly (i think so):

```
public QueryStringParser(string QueryString)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(QueryString))
            {
                this._mode = Mode.First;
            }
            else if (QueryString.Contains(_FristFieldName) && !QueryString.Contains(_SecondFieldName))
            {
                this._mode = Mode.Second;
            }
            else if (!QueryString.Contains(_FristFieldName) && QueryString.Contains(_SecondFieldName))
            {
                this._mode = Mode.Third;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("QueryString has wrong format");
            }
        }
```

There must'n't be both FieldNames in one QueryString.

How to change this code to be mo readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the determination of the Mode into a separate method and return the Mode value; that way you can eliminate the if-else statements

```
public QueryStringParser(string QueryString)
{
    this._mode = DetermineMode(QueryString);
}

private Mode DetermineMode(string QueryString)
{
    // Input is NULL STRING
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(QueryString))
        return Mode.First;

    bool hasFirst = QueryString.Contains(_FristFieldName);
    bool hasSecond = !QueryString.Contains(_SecondFieldName);

    // Query using FirstName
    if (hasFirst && !hasSecond)
        return Mode.Second;

    //Query using SecondName
    if (!hasFirst && hasSecond)
        return Mode.Third;

    //Insufficient info to Query data
    throw new ArgumentException("QueryString has wrong format");
}
```

[EDIT] Removed the double checking on the existance of field names and use variables instead.

Comment: Oops. Wrote an exactly same code before seeing your comment :)

Answer (score 6):

I would at least remove some duplication in checking the existing fields:

```
public QueryStringParser(string QueryString) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(QueryString))
        this._mode = Mode.First;
    else {
        bool has_1st = QueryString.Contains(_FristFieldName);
        bool has_2nd = QueryString.Contains(_SecondFieldName);
        if      ( has_1st && !has_2nd) this._mode = Mode.Second;
        else if (!has_1st &&  has_2nd) this._mode = Mode.Third;
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("QueryString has wrong format");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is readable, you could use some nesting on common conditions, to make parts clearer.

You cant use Switch because the comparison has to be to a static value.

Answer (score 2):

### Comments and Indentation

---

It is already good-looking.

```
public QueryStringParser(string QueryString)
        {
            // Input is NULL STRING
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(QueryString))
            {
                this._mode = Mode.First;
            }

            // Query using FirstName
            else if (QueryString.Contains(_FristFieldName) &&
                    !QueryString.Contains(_SecondFieldName))
            {
                this._mode = Mode.Second;
            }

            //Query using SecondName
            else if (!QueryString.Contains(_FristFieldName) &&
                      QueryString.Contains(_SecondFieldName))
            {
                this._mode = Mode.Third;
            }

            //Insufficient info to Query data
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("QueryString has wrong format");
            }
        }
```

I hope she looks Beautiful to you now...

GoodLUCK!!

Comment: It may be the example, but the comments you have added doesn't make anything clearer, the code is clear.

Comment: Well thats because i do NOT actually know the context of the code; i.e. what it is being used for. The comments i have placed are just meant to be placeholders to give Stremlenye an idea how the code would look. Eventually, Stremlenye will place the proper comments there i hope...

Comment: This looks more maintainable to me then mkj's method. If something changes, it is a tiny bit easier to modify this.

Answer (score 1):

The code is readable. You could make it shorter by removing the brackets as the statements are only one-liners:

```
public QueryStringParser(string QueryString)
        {
            //check if string is empty
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(QueryString))
                this._mode = Mode.First;
            else
            {
               bool hasFirst = QueryString.Contains(_FristFieldName);
               bool hasSecond= QueryString.Contains(_SecondFieldName);

               //check if string contains first field name but not second field name
               if (hasFirst  && !hasSecond)
                   this._mode = Mode.Second;
               //check if string contains second field name but not first field name
               else if (!hasFirst && hasSecond)
                   this._mode = Mode.Third;
               //default - error
               else
                   throw new ArgumentException("QueryString has wrong format");
            }
        }
```

Also - removed duplicate calls to the Contains method

I wouldn't suggest using any shorthand operators as these would make the code far less readable.

Lastly - in line comments!

Answer (score 1):

Use something like ReSharper or Refactor Pro! to help tidy up your code and encourage good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Use Switch case.

Comment: Switch may not be elegant here. As a single expression is not being evaluated in all the IFs...

Comment: you cant use a switch here the cases in switches must be fixed/static